# Class Implementations With Pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame

I'm attempting to write a program using pygame to create a class called `Dot()` that allows me to implement Dot objects, which will be small, 2 pixel radius circles. I'm trying to create them within my main game loop, but I keep getting the error message "name 'x' is not defined". I'm not sure why that would be the case. If it were going to throw such an error I would expect it to first say that color isn't defined, since it's listed first in the list of parameters. I'm not sure if my error is caused by the way I wrote the class itself or if it's something in my implementation of the class (I'm almost positive I did this wrong, but I've tried it a few different ways as well and keep getting the same error), or if it's or both.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random, pygame, sys
from random import randint 
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Version02')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED      = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN    = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE     = (  0,   0, 255)

class Dot():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y):
        self = pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, color, (x, y), 2, 0)
        self.color = getDotColor()
        self.x = getDotX()
        self.y = getDotY() 

    def getDotColor():
        color = random.choice([RED,  GREEN, BLUE])
        return color

    def getDotX():
        x = randint(0, 700)
        return x

    def getDotY():
        y = randint(0, 700)
        return y   

while True: #main game loop    
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)

    dot = Dot(color, x, y)#I'm not exactly sure how to implement this correctly  

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: `dot = Dot(color, x, y)` - what _are_ `x` and `y` here? Where do they come from? That `color` is somehow defined may be because you used `from pygame.locals import *`, and this imported the name `color`.

Comment: They're supposed to be the x and y coordinates for the location of the circle, and color would be the color of the circle. Supposed to be, though I know this is not the correct syntax. I'm just not sure what would be.

Comment: This _is_ correct syntax. The problem happens during execution, because, as the error message tells you, __name `x` is not defined__. Where is `x` defined? Can you output its value with `print(x)`? (Spoiler: you can't, for the same reason).

Comment: I thought I had defined x, y, and color in the class `Dot()`, which would be taken when I created an object of that class.

Comment: No, you didn't define them: you defined `self.x, self.y`, which are different. Anyway, when you do `Dot(color, x, y)` and get this error, it happens _before_ the attempt to instantiate `Dot` and, thus, before the call to `Dot.__init__`. Try this: create a new blank Python file and write `print(x)`. Then run this script. Why do you get this exact error message? What _is_ `x` here? (Spoiler: you cannot know, and nor can the Python interpreter, because this name is not defined)

Answer (score 1):

> dot = Dot(color, x, y)#I'm not exactly sure how to implement this correctly

You do not define a x or y value before. Your error comes from here. Same for the color.
If you want color and dot coordinates to be randomly created each time you create a Dot object (at least I understand this is what you are looking for) you have to rewrite the `__init__` method:

```
class Dot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = getDotColor()
        self.x = getDotX()
        self.y = getDotY()
        self = pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, self.color, (self.x, self.y), 2, 0)
```